# Silverstripe Cron Job Admin Actions

Tags: security, cron, silverstripe

I have a controller function whose permission is set to ADMIN that needs to be executed form a cron job, unfortuntly calling it from php or php-cgi says that the actipn is not permitted on the controller. I've temporarily removed the ADMIN check, but it's resource intensive so it's a possible DDOS vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom permission check in your controller to check if the call is made from the CLI:

```
class FooController extends Controller {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'mySecureAction' => '->MySecurityCheck'
    );

    public function mySecureAction() {
        // do something here
    }

    /**
     * if this method returns true, the action will be executed
     * for more information, view the docs at: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller#access-control
     */
    public function MySecurityCheck() {
        return Director::is_cli() || Permission::check('ADMIN');
    }
}
```